# invoke a HTTP delete method, using RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to implement a HTTP delete request from the user. So I got this in my HTML file,

```
<li><a href="/signout">Logout</a></li>
```

but in my routes file I got this:

```
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
```

and destroy is defined as:

```
  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

if I remove "via: delete" seems to work fine. But how do I invoke a DELETE method using HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy enough to do this if you're using the unobtrusive rails plugins for jquery or [other js libs].

```
<li><%= link_to "Logout", '/signout', method: :delete %></li>
```

That can be made prettier by naming the route with `as: :signout`, allowing you to use `signout_path` as the url helper.

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Answer (score 0):

See [Is it possible to trigger an HTTP DELETE request from an HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277149/is-it-possible-to-trigger-an-http-delete-request-from-an-html-form).

Basically you need to do it via `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/, I am following this tutorial, that's why I was wondering why the guys chose to write "via:delete"