# Trying to kick off an http delete but doesn't seem to work

Tags: html, forms, rest

Is it possible to fire off an http DELETE using an html form? I have an app that requires an http delete but when I try posting to it with my form, it tells me the method is not allowed and to try DELETE. Here is my form code:

```
<form method='delete' action='/groups/dissolve/$org_ID' />
<input class='btn btn-danger' type='submit' value='close group forever' style='font-size:82.5%' />
</form>
```

I am following instructions I found on this site: http://amundsen.com/examples/put-delete-forms/

When I use the REST client plugin for FireFox and send an http delete, it works. Does not work from the form I wrote above. Help?

Thanks

Comment: The link you provide in the question is a proposal with examples. They show how it would work if the proposal were implemented. It is not part of any spec yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope - you cannot code HTTP verbs like "DELETE" from an HTML 4.x or XHTML form:

- [Is it possible to trigger an HTTP DELETE request from an HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277149/is-it-possible-to-trigger-an-http-delete-request-from-an-html-form)
- [A proposal for supporting PUT and DELETE in HTML Forms](http://amundsen.com/examples/put-delete-forms/)

Comment: Thanks @paulsm4 for your quick response. You state that is cannot be done with HTML 4.x or XHTML. What about HTML 5?

Comment: @Progger: yes, I believe HTML 5 forms will support DELETE: http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/42827/1954

Answer (score 1):

(I assume that even thought it isn't possible in straight HTML that you still want to get it done.)

You can do it with a bit of Jquery:

[How to send a PUT/DELETE request in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153917/how-to-send-a-put-delete-request-in-jquery)

Override the submit button's behavior and call your own code to process the delete.

Comment: Of *course* you can do it in Javascript.  But that wasn't the question ;)

Comment: Thanks @Mike Johnston for helping me find the answer. I should have asked HOW (if not html) in my question.